# HTTP get request possible without passing very long string to URL?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, razor-pages

What is the most efficient way to pass a very long GET request? I see a similar question was posted here: [Very long http get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809244/very-long-http-get-request) which suggests using a post request instead of get? Why is this?

As an example, I have an application that includes 4 multiselectlists and a dropdown. The user can select several options to filter a table down and display the results. Currently this is included in my onget method by building a string in the URL and then running linq queries to display the results based on the user's selections. It works, but it seems very inefficient to me to pass such a long URL. Isn't there a better way to do this with model binding?

.cshtml file:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="CurSelDepts" asp-items="Model.DeptList" asp-for="SelDepts"></select>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="CurSelTechs" asp-items="Model.TechOneList" asp-for="SelTechs"></select>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="CurSelTech2s" asp-items="Model.TechTwoList" asp-for="SelTech2s"></select>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="CurSelRoles" asp-items="Model.RoleList" asp-for="SelRoles"></select>
<select class="form-control col-md-6" name="CurSelEmp" asp-items="Model.EmployeeList" asp-for="SelEmp">
    <option disabled selected style="display:none">--select--</option>
</select>
<input formmethod="get" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="searchbtn" />
```

.cs file:

```
public MultiSelectList DeptList { get; set; }
public MultiSelectList TechOneList { get; set; }
public MultiSelectList TechTwoList { get; set; }
public SelectList EmployeeList { get; set; }
public MultiSelectList RoleList { get; set; }
public int SelEmp { get; set; }
public int SelNewEmp { get; set; }
public int[] SelRoles { get; set; }
public int[] SelDepts { get; set; }
public int[] SelTechs { get; set; }
public int[] SelTech2s { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync(int[] selRoles, int[] curSelRoles, int selEmp, int curSelEmp, int[] selDepts, int[] curSelDepts, int[] selTechs, int[] curSelTechs, int[] selTech2s, int[] curSelTech2s)
{
    DeptList = new MultiSelectList(_context.ppcc_deptCds, "Id", "dept_cd", SelDepts);
    TechOneList = new MultiSelectList(_context.ppcc_techCds, "Id", "tech_cd", SelTechs);
    TechTwoList = new MultiSelectList(_context.ppcc_techTwoCds, "Id", "tech_cd_two", SelTech2s);
    RoleList = new MultiSelectList(_context.ppcc_roles, "Id", "role_nm", SelRoles);
    EmployeeList = new SelectList(_context.employees, "Id", "employee_nm", SelEmp);

    SelEmp = curSelEmp;
    SelDepts = curSelDepts;
    SelTechs = curSelTechs;
    SelTech2s = curSelTech2s;
    SelRoles = curSelRoles;

    IQueryable<ppcc_matrix> ppcc_matrixIQ = from s in _context.ppcc_matrices select s;

    if (curSelDepts.Any())  {ppcc_matrixIQ = ppcc_matrixIQ.Where(s => curSelDepts.Contains(s.ppcc_deptCdId));}
    if (curSelTechs.Any())  {ppcc_matrixIQ = ppcc_matrixIQ.Where(s => curSelTechs.Contains(s.ppcc_techCdId));}
    if (curSelTech2s.Any()) {ppcc_matrixIQ = ppcc_matrixIQ.Where(s => curSelTech2s.Contains(s.ppcc_techTwoCdId));}
    if (curSelRoles.Any())  {ppcc_matrixIQ = ppcc_matrixIQ.Where(s => curSelRoles.Contains(s.ppcc_roleId));}
    if (curSelEmp != 0) { ppcc_matrixIQ = ppcc_matrixIQ.Where(s => s.employeeId.Equals(curSelEmp)); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model Binding works with GET requests as well as POST requests. You just need to ensure that the public properties are decorated with the `BindProperty` attribute with `SupportsGet = true` (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-data-from-get-requests):

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
public Type MyProperty { get; set; }
```

As to very long URLs, there is a [limit to the length of  a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). POST requests also have limits imposed by servers, but it is very much larger by default. It needs to be to cater for file uploads, for example.

Comment: Yes, I neglected to mention that I've already tried this and it isn't working for me. However, I'm wondering if that's because in my html file, I don't have those select lists wrapped in: <form method="get"></form> . Could this be why, or should that matter?

Comment: A form submission will only include values from controls within a form, so yes, if your select elements are not inside a form, their selected values will not be included in the payload when the form is submitted.